# TypeScript 0.8.2 importing Node.js modules in internal modules

Tags: node.js, module, external, typescript, internal

Okay, as I can see you would like to use internal modules in your project. Well, there was a workaround in TypeScript 0.8.1.1, you could define non exported module (internal) and add imports above it. In 0.8.2 it seems that this doesn't work anymore. Only option I see here would be to completely omit import syntax and use standard require for node modules. I don't know if this is a good idea but please, share your opinions. I know that using import syntax will make module external (language specification), but that wasn't true in 0.8.1.1, bug maybe?

In TypeScript 0.8.1.1 this worked and doesn't work in 0.8.2 anymore:

```
import path = module('path');
import fs = module('fs');
module SomeNamespace.Controller {
    export class Index {
        ...
    }
}
```

I could reference file including above code using reference syntax on top of file in other internal modules and normally call:

```
var ctrl = new SomeNamespace.Controller.Index;
ctrl.index();
```

It seems that in 0.8.2 this is the only way what it works for internal modules:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
module SomeNamespace.Controller {
    export class Index {
        ...
    }
}
```

Are there any other possibilities to mix internal modules with Node.js modules? Is there something wrong with above require usage (it compiles and runs okay ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that TypeScript 0.8.2 takes us closer to the specification.

The syntax:

```
import x = module('SomeModule');
```

Is specifically an `ExternalModuleReference` in the TypeScript Language Specification.

An internal module would be imported using:

```
///<reference path="SomeModule.ts" />
import x = SomeModule;
```

But importing an internal module won't generate you a `require` statement in your JavaScript.

Taken from TypeScript Language Specification 0.8 - 9.2.2 Import Declarations

**ImportDeclaration:**

```
import Identifier = ModuleReference ;
```

**ModuleReference:**

```
ExternalModuleReference
ModuleName
```

**ExternalModuleReference:**

```
module ( StringLiteral )
```

Comment: Okay, so is it somehow possible to mix my internal modules with Node.js commonjs modules? As soon as I add import x = module(...) to my internal module, it becomes treated as an external one.

Comment: Can they be made external? The problem with just using a require in TypeScript is that it won't give you the type information on the variable.

Comment: Yes I know, but it is very inconvenient to load modules via import statement because I have to provide full paths to TypeScript files ... Any workaround about this?

Comment: So what is a best way for example to write a framework for Node.js entirely in TypeScript?

Comment: I would use external modules. MyModule.ts would `export class ...` and I'd load them with `import myModule = module('MyModule');`

Comment: I am doing just that, but it is a problem because I will have to distribute all classes instead of one combined output. It is a nightmare ... So if I understood everything right, there is no way to use internal modules together with Node.js?

Comment: Not really, but part of the beauty of "the node" is that you don't need one big JavaScript file - you just load the bits you need.

Comment: So, should I have each class in its own file and for example generate output in lib folder (js + d.ts). I would somehow like to package everything under same namespace ... Is that possible? And thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Normally with node you would organise into folders, which gives your namespace-esque organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this error is due to the version of the TypeScript.
In TypeScript  0.8.1.1 to import an external module the syntax has to be:

```
export import <moduleName> = module(“<path>”);
```

This is a bug identified in the latest version of TypeScript, you can return to the previous version or change the syntax to make it compatible with v0.8.1.1. Have in mind that this is a bug and in future versions, you should be able to use the original syntax.

This is the official thread for this bug:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/405800

Comment: As I wrote, in 0.8.1.1 import worked fine but in 0.8.2 the whole module isn't available anymore in another internal module. I guess this is the correct behavior (using import makes module external) and will be present in future versions?